# uninitialized constant REXMLUtiliyNodeString

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I made some small changes to a few views in my Rails 4 app and moved my Unicorn gem into the main section of my Gemfile, launched the server, and was greeted with the following right at the `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` line:

*`uninitialized constant REXMLUtiliyNodeString`*

WTF, mate?

My Google searching didn't lead me to much. About 9 results and nothing related to this `REXMLUtiliyNodeString` class. Same number of results when I searched for just `REXMLUtiliyNodeString` as well. I tried commenting the `csrf_meta_tags` out to see what happened, and my server gave me the same error on the next link containing a query string, the next form, etc.

I'm using the [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) gem, and when I looked at the value, it showed:

```
Session expired
>> undefined
```

Makes sense why the `csrf_meta_tags` are giving me an issue, but I don't see why the session is expired. Perhaps some of my server log will help. Here it is until the template rendering stuff:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

NameError - uninitialized constant REXMLUtiliyNodeString:
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:500:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
  rspec-core (2.14.5) lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:14:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:10:in `rescue in load_with_autoloading'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load_with_autoloading'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:93:in `_decrypt'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:63:in `decrypt_and_verify'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:461:in `decrypt_and_verify'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:476:in `[]'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:113:in `get_cookie'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:89:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:88:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:82:in `block in extract_session_id'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:81:in `extract_session_id'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:46:in `block in []'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:45:in `[]'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:67:in `id'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:282:in `current_session_id'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:288:in `session_exists?'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:140:in `exists?'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:160:in `load_for_read!'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:86:in `[]'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:194:in `form_authenticity_token'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:53:in `form_authenticity_token'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/csrf_helper.rb:21:in `csrf_meta_tags'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1806160678256643230_70323633825000'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
```

Can anyone please help point me in the right direction even if you don't know the answer? I'm 100% stumped and I need to push out some changes today.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I feel a tad dumb. This was another episode of the `Rails giving you error messages that aren't actually due to your Rails app` show.

All I did was clear my browser's cookies from the last day, and it worked. I had no idea there was that interaction.

Here's how to clear your cookies on any browser:

- [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582)
- [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-cookies-remove-info-websites-stored)
- [Safari](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph11920)
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/help/tutorials/security/privacy/)
- [Internet Explorer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/delete-manage-cookies#ie=ie-11)

Don't be another victim like me. Clear those cookies!